# How do I enable keyboard + mouse shortcuts on x11?

Tags: x11, input, garuda-linux

I'm using Garuda Linux with Gnome and I recently switched to X11 because I like to share my screen and play games, and wayland comes short specifically on that. I know Gnome isn't supposed to be used for gaming, but I genuinely liked the workflow it provides when I'm coding.

My problem here is that on wayland, I can simply hold <kbd>Super</kbd> and scroll to switch to another workspace. That doesn't work with X11. I have installed x11 gestures that provide me gestures for my touchpad but I'd rather use my mouse when I'm at home.

Anyone knows why kb + mouse shortcut combinations don't work on X11, and how I can fix it?

Answer (score 0):

It is not X11 that is the problem. KDE Plasma on X11 can do this. KDE is very customisable. If Gnome can not do it, then it is worth a try. (You can continue to run Gnome apps.)

Comment: Well it's not about the gnome apps haha, I just really love Gnome itself. I know KDE is very customizable, daily drove it for a few years but I found it a hassle to have a bunch of external things taking care of things that Gnome already has by default. Is there a way that maybe I could hack something together to handle what I need?